# Finding href, id and classes of all links in a web page

Tags: c#, html-parsing

I need to find all links in a web page and its href, id and class properties/attributes..

Even though all links would have only one href and id, it could have multiple classes and so classes will have to be captured in a list.

I found [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/scraping-html) to find all links and their href also found the [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples)

I'm not familiar with html parsing and so would appreciate if some one could help me in geting the id and classes for the links.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

htmlagilitypack is a great tool. You can use linq to search all 'a' tags in a web page.

let's look at this sample:

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://www.google.com");

 IEnumerable<HtmlNode> linkedPages = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a");
 foreach (var item in linkedPages)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Href : " + item.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty) +
    " id : " + item.GetAttributeValue("id", string.Empty) +
    " class : " + item.GetAttributeValue("class", string.Empty));
 }
```

Ludo

Comment: tx, so it does not provide me a list of class but a space separated string

Comment: id and href is fine but I was hoping to get the class in list format as class can have multiple values,currently I have split it and added to list but if its possible directly that would have been gr8